# PowerShell If Statement not returning expected results using array values

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to condense a PS script from 30+ lines of original code, down to a handful using an array. My original script has about 30+ (functional) lines of code to check the status of various web sites like this:

```
$icelb = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://interchange.ctdssmap.com/Connecticut/
```

Followed by the status that gets reported to the console:

```
    if ($icelb.StatusDescription -ne "OK") {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red  "Interchange Load Balancer Results: FAILED"
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, after 30+ lines of this, the script operates rather slowly, to say the least. So I am playing around with using arrays for the URL's instead, like this (the `$websites` variable contains an array of all the URL's to be tested):

```
$websites | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ | select $_.StatusDescription
    if ($_.StatusDescription -ne "OK") {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red  "'$_': FAILED"
    } else {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green   "'$_': " $_.StatusDescription
    }
}
```

My problem is in the reporting phase of the script. I can't get the `if` statement to properly recognize and report correct status. The only thing I repeatedly get is "'$_': FAILED", even though statusdescription is "OK".

I have just noticed that the variable `$_.StatusDescription` is empty, which is likely causing the problem, but I can't get the correct syntax to have the `if` statement properly evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "current object" variable doesn't work the way you seem to expect. In a statement

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ | select $_.StatusDescription
```

*both* occurrences of `$_` are expanded at parse time, so upon execution the statement effectively looks like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://example.com/foo/bar' | select 'https://example.com/foo/bar'.StatusDescription
```

To make your code work simply expand the property `StatusDescription`, assign the value to a variable, and use that variable in your `if` statement:

```
$websites | ForEach-Object {
    $status = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ |
              Select-Object -Expand StatusDescription
    if ($status -ne "OK") {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red "'$_': FAILED"
    } else {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green "'$_': $status"
    }
}
```

Comment: OK so while Angsar was answering (THANK YOU!!!!!) I managed to get my code down to one line as follows:

$websites | ForEach-Object {(write-host "$_ :" (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ | Select-Object -Expand StatusDescription))}

But the results were still giving me: https://modellg2.ctdssmap.com/state/lg2/ : @{StatusDescription=OK}

Ansgar's hint about the -Expand switch did the trick!!

https://modellg2.ctdssmap.com/state/lg2/ : OK

THANK YOU!!! :) :)

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain what you consider wrong about this answer?

Comment: Hey Ansgar :) I didn't vote it down? To the best of my knowledge it accepted the answer and approved it. It was great and totally fulfilled the request. I appreciate the assistance! Completely. Was it someone else perhaps? Check it out, I gave it the green check right away...
(ugh I can't paste a screenshot in here) - but it's still marked green check on my side?

Comment: @JPM I know it wasn't you. You'll get the "vote down" privilege once you reach 125 rep.